# Understanding reduce()

Tags: swift, reduce

Suppose I've a code where I want to calculate the average of the numbers using the higher order function `reduce()`:

```
var ofAvg = [1,2,3,4,5]

var doAvg = ofAvg.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }

doAvg/ofAvg.count //This gives me the correct answer which in this case is 3.
```

But when I do:

```
var ofAvg = [1,2,3,4,5]

var doAvg = ofAvg.reduce(0) { ($0 + $1)/ofAvg.count }
```

I get the output as `1`. What wrong I'm I doing? Is my understanding of `reduce()` not what it actually is? Is it possible to get the average without having to do `doAvg/ofAvg.count` outside the `reduce()` method?

Comment: You're dividing by the count on each iteration.

Comment: You need to divide by the number of elements only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the division only once, after all summing is done:

```
var ofAvg = [1,2,3,4,5]

var doAvg = ofAvg.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 } / ofAvg.count
```

You don't even need seperate closure in this case, since `+` already has the same type that you're looking for (`(Int, Int) -> Int`), so you can just use it directly:

```
var doAvg = ofAvg.reduce(0, combine: +) / ofAvg.count
```

*P.S.* Please use better names. Variables should be nouns (or noun phrases), and functions should be verbs (or verb phrases).

Comment: That did it. I completely forgot `reduce()` does its operation on each element of the array. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: It takes minimum 9 minutes. I will once I can. Thanks again! :)